# Calling constructors of certain classes based upon a common parameter c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism, parameter-passing

I'm currently working on class inheritance/polymorphism in my classes and I can't figure out this problem. Ok here it is: Let's say I have 2 mock classes, and I let the user choose a value that corresponds to the last parameter in the constructor:

```
class Planets {
private:
    int x,y,z;
    string a;
public:
    Planets(string name, int diameter, int mass, int planet_kind) : a(name), x(diameter), y(mass), z(planet_kind) { }
    Planets() { a="", x=0, y=0, z=0; }

    //get and set functions to manipulate data

    virtual void planet_creation(Planets& p1);
    //function I want to modify depending on the planet
}
```

The thing to pay attention to is the planet_kind variable. I want the parent class to be a baseline for the others for example, gas giants would be 2, planets with life would be 1, etc... They would all have their own classes and constructors. For example in another class:

```
class Gas_giant : public Planets {
private:
    int x,y,z;
    string a;
public:
    Gas_giant(string name, int diameter, int mass, int planet_kind) : a(name), x(diameter), y(mass), z(planet_kind) { }
    Gas_giant() { a="Gas", x=0, y=0, z=2; }

    //get and set functions to manipulate data

    void planet_creation(Gas_giant& g);
    //function I want to modify depending on the planet
    //example: gas giants would be larger when created,have no solid mass,high gravity
}
```

basically I want the user to be able to input the kind of planet and the name, then depending on the kind they choose, call certain types of planets to be randomly generated in different ways. The functions aren't the problem, the issue I'm having is getting my program to choose different constructors based upon a parameter in a base constructor.

I don't want my program to create any "Type 0 " planets, it's just a class I'm trying to derive all the rest from.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are languages in which a constructor can return a derived type, but C++ is not one of them. In C++ a constructor always constructs precisely its own type.

Anyway, it's not obvious that using a "planet_kind" integer is superior to using a different constructor. The different constructor option is likely to be quite a bit more readable:

```
Planet* henry = new GasGiant("Henry", ...);
Planet* bob   = new Asteroid("Bob", ...);
...
```

If you really needed to use an enum for some reason (such as reading the data from a file), then you'll need a case statement:

```
for (;;) {
  // read data into name, size, mass, kind
  planets.emplace_back( make_planet(name, size, mass, kind) );
}

...

Planet* make_planet(std::string name, double radius, double mass, enum PlanetKind kind) {
  switch (kind) {
    case GIANT   : return new GasGiant(name, radius, mass);
    case ASTEROID: return new Asteroid(name, radius, mass);
    // ...
    default: // write an error message
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I had toyed with using an enum, but I was trying to use it as a parameter of the constructor, (I knew wouldn't work but I tried anyway). So saying I have maybe 6 options for the user to choose from, would it be best to use and enum and a switch statement?
And how do I let the user enter an enum type object?

Comment: @Shilaly: if you don't know the type at compile time, the enum-and-switch statement is the easiest solution. If you do know the type at compile time, you should just use the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for a clear and concise answer, as opposed to overly verbose and riddled with jargon a newbie like me wouldn't understand. +1